# stepping into zipper with `to` lens

Tags: haskell, types, haskell-lens, zipper

I'm struggling with [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) and [zippers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zippers). Consider below code run in `ghci`

```
> import Control.Lens
> import Control.Zipper
> 
> :t within (ix 1) $ zipper ([1,2,3] :: [Int]) 
> within (ix 1) $ zipper ([1,2,3] :: [Int])
   :: Control.Monad.MonadPlus m => m (Zipper Top Int [Int] :>> Int)
```

Having `data A t = A t`, how can I create type of zipper like: `Control.Monad.MonadPlus m => m (Zipper Top Int [Int] :>> A Int)`?

I tried `within (ix 1 . to A) $ zipper ([1,2,3] :: [Int])` but it gives an error:

```
Could not deduce (Contravariant
                    (Bazaar (Indexed Int) (A Int) (A Int)))
  arising from a use of ‘to’
from the context (Control.Monad.MonadPlus m)
  bound by the inferred type of
           it :: Control.Monad.MonadPlus m =>
                 m (Zipper Top Int [Int] :>> A Int)
  at Top level
In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘to A’
In the first argument of ‘within’, namely ‘(ix 1 . to A)’
In the expression: within (ix 1 . to A)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make an `Iso` and compose with that. In ghci:

```
> import Control.Lens
> import Control.Zipper
>
> data A t = A t
> let _A = iso A (\(A a) -> a)
>
> let a = within (ix 1 . _A) $ zipper ([1,2,3] :: [Int])
> :t a
a :: MonadPlus m => m (Zipper Top Int [Int] :>> A Int)
> a ^? _Just . focus
Just (A 2)
```

Edit: The reason you need `(\(A a) -> a)` is so you can get back out.

```
> data A t = A t
> let _A = iso A (error "Can't unA")
>
> let a = within (ix 1 . _A) $ zipper ([1,2,3] :: [Int])
> a ^? _Just . focus
Just (A 2)
> fmap upward a ^? _Just . focus
Just [1,*** Exception: Can't unA
```

I don't think there's a valid way to make this without a function for extracting `A`. You could write an invalid `Traversal` but it still won't work properly:

```
> data A t = A t
> let _A f a = a <$ f (A a)
>
> let a = within (ix 1 . _A) $ zipper ([1,2,3] :: [Int])
> let b = a & _Just . focus .~ A 10
> b ^? _Just . focus
Just (A 10)
> fmap upward b ^? _Just . focus
Just [1,2,3] -- Should be Just [1, 10, 3]
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without specyfing `(\(A a) -> a)` function? Can I just pass here `undefined` if in my case it is not that obvious?

Comment: Not really. The problem is you won't be able to go back up. Using `upward` to get back out would give an `undefined`.

Comment: I see... Are there any other options than `Iso`?

Comment: `Traversal` is the 'weakest' you can use but you'll still need `(\(A a) -> a)` to make a valid `Traversal`. I don't advice writing an invalid one like I did in my edit since it could lead to some nasty bugs.

Comment: okay, I'll try to workaround `unA` somehow. Thanks for other options and explaination!